# Can I make [subsidy halving] in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

I want to make new coin in solidity.
I found the code how to make subsidy halving in Bitcoin clone coding.
Can I make subsidy halving in solidity?(ERC-20, 721, 1155 whatever)
I can't find any subsidy halving in ERC coin.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to assume that you mean: "Bitcoin Halving." Given that is the case, in Solidity, what is available is: "**Token burning**".

To ensure that you understand: Bitcoin Halving is an event that occurs where the block reward given to Bitcoin miners for processing transactions is cut in half.

Token Burning in Ethereum is a way of removing tokens from circulation by sending the tokens to a "dead address" this renders the token "unspendable." This is often done to reduce the amount of the said token in circulation. This ultimately affects the token liquidity.

The simple function below illustrates Polygon [MATIC](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0#code) token burning:

```
function _burn(address account, uint256 value) internal {
    require(account != address(0));

    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(value);
    _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(value);
    emit Transfer(account, address(0), value);
}
```

The above function is part of the functions deployed when initializing a token contract in solidity. With this function as part of the deployed contract code, you can burn any token type: ERC20, ERC721 ...

You will find this resource useful to understand more: https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/what-is-a-coin-burn